# Prevent APPCRASH notification for Excel 2000 running on Windows 8.1

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, office-2000

I'm using Office 2000 on Windows 8.1 (a perfectly legal copy bought many years ago). It works great...but although I can work on XLS files, every time I close Excel, the following dialog appears twice:

[image: APPCRASH message]

The problem details are:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: EXCEL.EXE
  Application Version:  9.0.0.3822
  Application Timestamp:    38b691e8
  Fault Module Name:    TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll
  Fault Module Version: 12.0.30501.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5361f4c0
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00020f89
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.768.101
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0283
  Additional Information 2: 028301a715e52c93c058ba8fb9cfc82e
  Additional Information 3: 3672
  Additional Information 4: 367280f587d42775bbacae3c183da840
```

I've tried changing the compatibility of the application, but it doesn't help. Word 2000 works (and closes) fine with no compatibility changes. Although it would be great to resolve the issue, I really just don't want to be notified.

So I have three questions:

```
1) Is it possible to tell Windows not to notify me of the APPCRASH for this application?
2) More specifically, can I tell Windows not to notify me of APPCRASH on application close only?
3) Is there a simple way to resolve this error?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew! Ok, after doing further online research I found a resolution to the underlying problem. I am a developer and have installed Visual Studio 2013. After performing a full search on my HDD, I found two copies of TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll:

```
* C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\12.0\amd64
* C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\12.0\x86
```

I ran the command prompt in Administrator mode, navigated to each of the above locations and ran the command:

```
regsvr32 /u TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll
```

This failed in the "amd64" folder but succeeded in the "x86" folder. After unregistering the DLL, Excel 2000 now closes without error!

This answer has been adapted from [this original answer](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_27873685.html).

While this does not resolve the original question of asking Windows not to notify me of the APPCRASH, it does solve the underlying issue.